# How to save upsetr graph as an image file from within function?

Tags: r, image, upsetr

UpSetR graphs are not saving properly when I call `f`. What is being saved to `tmp.tiff` is a blank image file. If I debug into the function, then it saves properly.

```
f <- function(tmp){
  tmp <- tmp %>% 
    fromList() %>% 
    upset()
  tiff(filename = 'tmp.tiff')
  tmp
  dev.off()
}

list(a = c(1, 1, 2, 6), b = c(2, 2, 3, 7)) %>%
  f()
```

I've saved the graph to a variable, called the tiff function for a file stream, called the graph variable and then `dev.off()`. What am I missing here?

edit:

```
#Calling tiff before upset does not work either.
f <- function(tmp){
  tiff(filename = 'tmp.tiff')
  upset(fromList(tmp))
  dev.off()
}

list(a = c(1, 1, 2, 6), b = c(2, 2, 3, 7)) %>%
  f()
```

Comment: You need to call `tiff` _before_ you call `upset`.

Comment: It is still saving a blank image for me.

Comment: If you just run `upset(fromList(YourData))` at the console (not in a function),  does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

if this is still a problem, I think you can find a solution here:

https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR/issues/115#issuecomment-1416486255

It seems that you need to `print` the plot to be able to save it inside a function. I don't know why, just came across it after reading this question.